# Why does Ubuntu 18.04 Server setup forces /boot outside of LVM configuration?

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, lvm

In ubuntu 16.04 server I used to setup my machines with one LVM only partition (full disk PV/VG) and split in two LV : root (mount / ext4) and swap.
This has proved impossible to do in 18.04 server setup as it try to force me to use a local disk partition (outside of LVM) to mount /boot on.
I'm aware that putting /boot inside the LVM is a bit risky but putting /boot in it's own partition is not what I want.
Is there a valid reason that forces this choice for boot in 18.04?

Thx

Comment: Welcom to AskUbuntu! I think answers to this related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199586/why-it-is-not-recommended-to-put-boot-partition-on-lvm can answer the WHY. As for the choice NOT to have a separate `/boot`, you can easily create the partition scheme you like during installation.

Comment: Thank you, but the setup refuses to proceed with when only / is mounted on the LV, it specifically states that it want an extra partition on local disk for /boot.

Comment: Do you need `/boot` to be a LV or you don't want a separate `/boot` at all? In the first case, maybe the installer complaints about a "missing" separete `/boot` and not about its format...

Comment: I don't want separate /boot. But the intaller wants it separate as soon as I put / on a LV.If I put / on a normal partition, the installer doesn't bother with /boot anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an [oddity of the live disc](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1785332). Just use the regular ubuntu server installation discs and you can do this.